# Duplicating an older SO question that may be out of date, what is the protocol?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I would like to know what web frameworks are available for Scala. However this question has been asked and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/what-scala-web-frameworks-are-available) but about a year ago. Some of the answers do roll into this year but with less detail than the first 5 or 6 people who answered and are obviously (perhaps) the most knowledgable. I would like their views a year on and any from new SO entrants.

- Should i just duplicate the question and explain why?
- Or go and answer the question with another question and see if anyone responds?
- Or ....... ?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have tried all of the specific Scala "question" sites (AKA Forums) and not received an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Or ....... ?

This. Don't post a duplicate, and *definitely* don't post a question as an answer.

Stack Overflow is not a forum. And even forums don't take kindly to folks re-posting the same question over and over again, just in case something's changed since the last time it was answered. On SO, if a new framework is added or an old one changes, the existing answers can be edited... By *anyone* who cares enough to keep them up-to-date.

If this doesn't happen (because, say, someone asked for a big list of things instead of presenting a specific problem to be solved), then perhaps the question should be removed entirely. If you feel this is the case, flag for moderator attention and justify this action. But even then, don't repost it - it'll only become out-of-date again...

> I would like their views a year on and any from new SO entrants.

The last answer posted to that question was added in March. The last edit to the accepted answer was made in April. If the question is out of date, it's not because folks have *forgotten about it*.

Comment: But the person who has a question can't edit the existing answers, because he's not able to answer it in the first place. Just leaving a comment to ask users to edit the answers won't bump it to the front page (rightly so), so how would you ever get the required attention to get up to date answers in?

Comment: In which case, adding a bounty is probably the right way to go <- the OP certainly has [enough rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/164394/purplepilot) for it.

Comment: @ivo: so how does he know the answers are out-of-date then?

Comment: Because he tried them and they didn't work?!?

Comment: @ivo: then the solution is a question SAYING THAT, not another "give me every possible answer including those I've already tried" dup...

Answer (score 2):

Please do not answer the question with another question, this is never the right course of action.

If you want to attract more answers to the question, an acceptable method would be to place a bounty on the question.  However, this question appears to be a polling question as there isn't a definative answer, rather it is likely there are many frameworks available, each equally as correct as the last.

I would suggest that perhaps this question is not best-suited to Stack Overflow.